# Fill the date time view with current date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to fill the textbox field with the current date automatically when the page loads and still be able to edit it but when I place 'datetime.now' it does not seem to work

this is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReturnedDate, "Returned date", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnedDate,DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()),new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "box" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReturnedDate)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just set the value of `ReturnedDate` in your model before you pass it to the view (and use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReturnedDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "box" })` to format it

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your date something like below.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReturnedDate, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })
```